# Problem with baking normal map

Tags: baking, normal-map

I've been trying to figure out how to get a normal map from my highpoly mesh to a low poly mesh (which is just the high poly decimated a few times.)
I've followed a few different tutorials and I keep getting the same results so I thought I'd ask for some help.
I smart uv project the low poly mesh, then I add a normal map and image texture node  and set it to non colour data and make sure thats still selected. I select the high poly, then the low poly and go into the cycles settings and make sure 'Selected to Active' is ticked then press bake. I'm left with this:

[image]

I'm not sure it's an unwrapping issue, topology issue. Some help would be appreciated if you can!
Thanks

Comment: @moonboots This is probably a really stupid question but it's saying the files too big - I compressed it but then it's not letting me upload as it isn't a .blend file.

Comment: Yeah I've deleted everything that isn't the two meshes and the file is still too big.

Comment: It's all deleted an it's still 79.6mb. Would I be able to share a google drive link?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZM0TRhAiZQPDKVqe7kmtDU0_M-evvF1X/view?usp=sharing    Let me know if this works

Comment: I'm glad to see it's working but even with that change I'm still getting the same results :( Can you show me exactly what you did? I must be getting a step wrong. I have selected to active on in the baking tab, do you change and other settings? Ive put what my screen looks like in the answers.

Comment: put the 2 pumpkins at the exact same position, unwrap the low-poly, give it a material with an Image Texture (not plugged for the moment), create the image, choose Bake Type > Normal, Selected to Active, Extrusion > 0.2. Then bake. Then plug the Image Texture into a Normal Map node that you plug into the Normal socket of the Principled BSDF or of the Diffuse

Comment: Im getting somewhere but this is still what I'm getting - I'll add a screen capture as a answer. I'm sorry!

Comment: please don't use the Your Answer fields to comment, it is only for people who want to give answers, instead edit your original post

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure how to add images.

Comment: Could you please share your file as it is just before the Bake step?

Comment: I got it to work! Thanks so much for taking the time to help. I've been trying to figure out what I''ve been doing wrong for weeks!

Comment: so what did you do wrong?

Comment: I didn't have the bake type as normal :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the 2 pumpkins at the exact same position, unwrap the low-poly (for example with *Smart UV Project* method), give it a material with an *Image Texture* (not plugged for the moment), create the image (make sure that you create a *32-bit Float*), select the high-poly, shift select the low-poly, choose *Bake Type > Normal*, *Selected to Active*, *Extrusion* > 0.2. Then bake. Then plug the *Image Texture* into a *Normal Map* node that you plug into the *Normal* socket of the *Principled BSDF* or of the *Diffuse*.

[image]

[image]